# How to register only a capital letter for keyPress, rather than 'Shift' along with it

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with a game I am creating that takes input and compares it against a pre-selected statement to see if the input matches. However, I find that for my 'keyPress' variable, when I want to input a capital letter, 'Shift' is registered as a character along with the capital letter. So, for instance, when I have to enter 'T-h-e' for 'The' I end up registering '"Shift"-T-h-e'. How can I get 'Shift' to not register, and only have the capital letter register?

Here's my function:

```
    function keyPress(e) {
      let char = e.key;
      console.log(char.value);
      let letter_we_are_on = selected_quotation.charAt(i);

      if (char === letter_we_are_on) {
        userInput.textContent += char;
        console.log('correct');
        roundScore += 1;
        i++; ...
      }
    }
```

Also, I've tried this in place of the second line, but it's not working:

```
    if (!(e.key === 'Shift')) {
      char = e.key
    }
```

Is there a reason this doesn't work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let p= document.getElementById('content');
document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
  const keyName = event.key;
  p.innerHTML += keyName;
});
```

```html
<h4>Type text</h4>
<p id='content'></p>
```